# Intentionally return NaN

Tags: c++, nan

I'm writing a ray tracer and part of the process is firing a ray that may or may not hit an object (geometric object). A number of the equations that describe objects return NaN naturally if no intersection happened (the intersection is imaginary) but not all of the objects return NaN if no intersection happened.

I know that I could force returning sqrt(-1) if no intersection happened, but I was wondering if there is a way to return this in a less expensive way.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This should work:

```
#include <limits>

return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
```

Comment: I guess it took me a minute to look up the proper header. :) I'll leave this for now, I think it's marginally better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 18):

```
return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
```

Answer (score 8):

I know it's an old question, but with C++11 you have the `nan(const char*)` family of functions (`nan` for doubles, `nanl` for long doubles and `nanf` for floats). The argument is implementation specific, but passing an empty string (e.g. `nan("")`) returns a generic NaN value.

Comment: Here's a reference to the `nan` function:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/nan-function/

Answer (score 2):

The `NAN` macro from `math.h` also works.

Comment: Should probably use `<cmath>` instead of `<math.h>` in C++.